# Opening an xlsx document in WebDav prompts for rename

Tags: c#, excel, webdav

We have a WebDav server written in C# that allows users to access documents. Normally, when a document is opened via file explorer, the user is able to make changes and save the document back with no issues. However, if an xlsx document is opened, the user is greeted with the following message:

`The file has been renamed. We recommend saving it now to get the new name`.

If you attempt to save, it fails saying

`You file was renamed, but something went wrong and your recent changes can't be saved.`

At this point, the user can use "Save A Copy" to save the file and override the file on the server as if it was a different document.

Since all other documents work fine (including other Office documents) I think the issue is with Excel rather than our code.

Comment: You have tagged your question with C#, but I don't quite see yet where C# comes into the picture. Could you edit your question to elaborate on that? If, however, your question is not related to programming, I am afraid that it is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Our WebDav server is written in C#, if there is a code solution to the issue, it would need to be in C#.